Column footer and table footer / two rows in column footer
I want to have the below three rows below the detail band of the table:

I was able to do first row as column footer as shown here:

And I tried to add a table footer for the second row as below by grouping columns 2 to 5. Column footer does not have option to add a second row.

But I get the below design in which the grouped columns moved to next row, instead of same row. Also grouping table footer columns gets column footer also grouped.

In general, what is the recommended way to add multiple rows in column footer / table footer.
